# Application of styling widgets in jQuery seems to differ

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my code snippet I demonstrate how I'm applying different classes to two different `accordion` widgets using `#divId .class`. This works great, but when I try to apply style to the `dialog` widget, it doesn't perform the same. I can't figure it out. Why do the same rules not apply? I'm new to jQuery.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog();
});

$(function() {
  $("#dialog2").dialog();
});

$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion();
});

$(function() {
  $("#accordion2").accordion();
});
```

```css
#dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: red;
}
#dialog2 .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: green;
}
#accordion .ui-accordion-header {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: red;
}
#accordion2 .ui-accordion-header {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog">
  <h3>1</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>2</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div id="dialog2" title="Dialog 2">
  <h3>1</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>2</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>1</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>2</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div id="accordion2">
  <h3>1</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>2</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI wraps only the dialog content in the id provided. You cannot use the id to style the title of the dialog.

You can use `aria-describedby` attribute to select and style a specific dialog. The value of this attribute is set to the id of the dialog element.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog, #dialog2").dialog();

  $("#accordion, #accordion2").accordion();
});
```

```css
[aria-describedby="dialog"] .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: red;
}
[aria-describedby="dialog2"] .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: green;
}
#accordion .ui-accordion-header {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: red;
}
#accordion2 .ui-accordion-header {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog">
  <h3>1</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>2</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div id="dialog2" title="Dialog 2">
  <h3>1</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>2</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>1</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>2</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div id="accordion2">
  <h3>1</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>2</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The element that you call `dialog()` on is not the outer wrapper that the title bar is in...the title is a sibling since the plugin wraps your element with an outer element that contains both.

There is an option to set a class on this outer wrapper:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({dialogClass: "dialog-red"});
```

Then in css:

```
.dialog-red .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    dialogClass: "dialog-red"
  });
});
```

```css
.dialog-red .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog">
  <h3>1</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>2</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>
```